# jQuery import error in chrome extension -- TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createElement')

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

when I try to import jQuery, it keeps giving me an error. It works fine on a normal browser, but when using chrome, I get:

```
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createElement')
    at $ (jQuery.min.js:2:7715)
    at jQuery.min.js:2:20695
    at jQuery.min.js:2:21025
    at jQuery.min.js:2:220
    at jQuery.min.js:2:225`
```

I just downloaded the latest version of jQuery from the website, and it used to  work before. I am importing it uing:
`<script src="jQuery.min.js"></script>`  in my popup.html and  `importScripts('./jQuery.min.js');`  in my background.js.

I am using manifest v3

```
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self';"
  },
  "host_permissions": [
    "*://*/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [{
    "js": ["background.js", "jQuery.min.js", "popup.js"],
    "matches": ["*://*.com/*"]
  }],
  "description": "Base Level Extension",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "scripting",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": { 
    "default_title": "Extension",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  }
```

I looked for an answer, but found nothing like this issue. Tried to use the online version of jQuery but chrome says its unsafe.

Comment: I would work to migrate away from jQuery to modern JavaScript which has evolved to handle much of the reason jQuery was created to handle multiple browsers code  idiosyncrasies.

Comment: The service worker doesn't have DOM so you can't use jQuery there. Also don't duplicate the same script as a content script: background.js must be loaded only via `service_worker` and popup.js only inside html file specified in `default_popup`.